# JWT and Session: how JWT should be properly used instead of Session

Tags: session, jwt

I am working on a project with PHP and angular. For the user sign in, we're using JWT. Still can't understand why we should use JWT instead of Sessions if each time the user browse a component we need to send the token to server code to check if the user still signed in or not.

Username and password will be sent to server code, where the authentication process will happen, and then generate a token and send it back to angular then save at the local storage.

Any comment on how JWT should be properly used.

**EDIT**

My question is about the process of checking the JWT when user surf the site and go from component into another.

Comment: My question is about the process of checking the JWT when user surf the site and go from component into another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JWT already is a proof of your authentication. So you have to send it with each request but you can simplify the authentication logic on server-side.

While on the login you will have to check the credentials you can rely on the JWT's signature and `expiryDate`. If the signature is still correct the token is valid and you do not have to authenticate anymore.

So regarding your horizontal authentication.
If the called service needs to be authenticated you have to check the JWT for validity on each request (normally works reasonably fast). If there are open api calls you can of course ignore the JWT on server side.

At the end of the day there is no difference to your "session" which will also send some "secret" key which maps your session context. Therefore, it will also be validated. 
For some backends you can also use the JWT as your session key to get both worlds involved.

**Example:**

lets say you have two api roots:

```
api/secured/*
api/open/*
```

(Note that the `secured` and `open` are only here for demonstrative purposes)

The `secured` part will contain all the services you want to be authenticated.
The `open` part can contain insensitive data as well as your login services:

```
api/open/login -> returns your token
api/open/token/* -> refresh, check re-issue whatever you might need
```

So now lets say the user accesses your site. You will want to provde an authentication error if he tries to access any `api/secured/*` URL without a proper JWT. 
In this case you can then redirect him to your login and create a token after authenticating him.

Now when he calls an `api/secured/*` URL your client implementation has to provide the JWT (Cookie, Request header, etc...). 
Depending on your framework, language etc. you can now provide an interceptor/filter/handler on server side which will check:

1. If the JWT is present
2. if the signature is valid (otherwise the token was faked)
3. if the JWT is still valid (expiryDate)

Then you can act accordingly.

So to sum up:
There is no need to "authenticate" unless you want to create a new token.
In all other cases it is enough to check the validity of your JWT

Comment: Is there any practical example.

Comment: To give a practical example I would need a little more context. I will ad one example, maybe this will help you out already

Comment: Just how to check the validity of the token ?

Comment: There are a lot of libraries supporting this. You can just pass them the token and the key you used to generate it and it will be validated using the content and the signature. If you want to have a homebrew solution you can also simply persist the token in the database or server context and do a simple compare

Comment: Just one more thing: can you propose a library for that ?

Comment: https://jwt.io is a good site explaining everything about jwt. They have a list of libraries and what they support for each language, including python

Answer (score 1):

If you use session for your application... Then while horizontal scaling sharing the session data becomes a burden ....you either need a specialised server .. Jwt are stateless and have no such requirement. It contain following data

Header - information about the signing algorithm, the type of payload (JWT) and so on in JSON format

Signature - well... the signature

Payload - the actual data (or claims if you like) in JSON format

Comment: My question is about the process of checking the JWT when user surf the site and go from component into another.